# Антивирус AVG и adb.exe

Tags: android, adb

Антивирус AVG переместил файл adb.exe в карантин. Android Studio не запускается. Что делать?

Comment: Вытащи из карантина  https://avg.softok.info/voprosy/avg-kak-ubrat-iz-karantina

Comment: И внеси в исключения.